# Casting variable into its own type

Tags: c, casting

in an existing code base written by someone I cannot ask anymore, I see quite some instances of casting a variable into its own type.

```c
uint32_t message_id = [...];
[...]
switch ((uint32_t)message_id)
{
[...]
```

It's too many occurences to just say it's left-over from e.g. changing the type of the variable at a later point.

If I try it out in compiler explorer, the compiler generates identical assembly with `-O0`.

Can anyone think of a reason, the developer might have done it that way?

Comment: Some people like to be able to always see the type of a variable. Some will put the type in the naming (e.g. u32message_id) others will insert an obvious cast. That's my guess anyway

Comment: One reason for a redundant cast -- which does *not* apply here -- is when you're printing an abstract type with `printf`.  For example, if you have `pid_t pid = getpid(); printf("pid: %d\n", (int)pid);`, the cast is necessary to match the format specifier `%d` in case type `pid_t` is something other than `int`, but it's redundant in the case that `pid_t` *is* `int`.  But that's obviously not what's going on here.

Comment: @MortenJensen Ignoring discussions about whether "Hungarian notation" is good or harmful, casting a variable to it's declared type is definitely 100% harmful. It gives a high probability of creating bugs and accidentally silencing valid compiler messages.

Comment: @Lundin: Any idea what sort of bugs it could introduce?

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for the explanation of a valid use case. :) ... Even if it does not apply here.

Comment: @Bugfinger Most obviously, it risks turning simple typos into severe bugs:  `void f (uint32_t* x) { ... switch( (uint32_t) x) ...`. And with the cast you've told the compiler that you know what you are doing, effectively shutting it off.

Comment: @Bugfinger Another classic example of a cast masking a bug is `char *p = (char *)malloc(10)`.  If you've forgotten to include `<stdlib.h>`, the compiler will tend to assume that `malloc` returns `int`.  But if (as is common, and true on the machine where I'm typing this) `int` is 32 bits but pointers are 64, this is a severe bug.  (It's less likely these days, because a modern compiler will complain about an undeclared function, regardless of the cast.)

Comment: @Lundin I agree with you. I am only trying to imagine the rationale for adding useless casts all over.

Comment: @bugfinger The compiler will generate a "cast from integer to pointer of different size" warning. So that's not shutting the compiler off.

Comment: The obvious example of where those useless casts become harmfull is if you ever change the type. E.g. to uint64_t because you need a message_id 0x100000001. Now that gets cast to 1 and mistaken for a different message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I cannot see any reason for that. You should remove them to make the code more readable.

If you want to explicitly document the type of a variable at some point of usage (like Morten suggested in the comment) you could add a comment instead.

Comment: I am removing the casts now. However, I consider adding comments for this bad because comments grow old too quickly.